# Excel as a data source in SSRS Query a Specific Column of a Sheet

Tags: excel, reporting-services, datasource

I want to query the data from an excel file utilizing ODBC System DSN for Excel 12.0.

What will be the right syntax to query specific columns from a worksheet and not the whole worksheet like this example:

SELECT 'Sheet1$'.* FROM 'Sheet1$'**

I need to be able to not query all of them and also not let import blank rows.

Comment: As suggested below, you can't connect to Excel directly from SSRS, but you can do it through SQL Server. There are lots of limitations with trying to use a file as a data source, you should consider loading the data into a table in a database first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use OPENROWSET. If you Excel file has column headers then you can do something like

```
Select MyFirstColumn, MySecondColumn, MyThridColumn, MyLastColumn FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=\\myServer\MyPath\MyFile.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [myWorkSheet$]')
```

If you have no row headers then set `HDR=NO` and use columns names `F1, F2....F99` etc.

You can add a where clause to filter out blank lines just as you would with a regular table.

**Note** you will need to allow ad-hoc queries and and make sure the provider is installed on the esrver. There are plenty of articles on how to do this, it's pretty simple.

Also remember that the path must be visible to the server, not just your local workstation.